# docker process not running in background

Tags: docker

Im trying to create a  ubuntu docker image but the process is not running in the background when I check the process.

Here are the commands

```
PREMs-MacBook-Pro:Documents prem$ docker run ubuntu:16.04 grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
PREMs-MacBook-Pro:Documents prem$ docker run ubuntu:16.04 grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
PREMs-MacBook-Pro:Documents prem$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: Why do you think `docker run ubuntu:16.04 grep ...` would run in the background, especially given that it's printing the output right in front of you?

Comment: when I do a docker ps, it does not list the 'container id'..When I add ps -a, it list all the process..On your question the background, I did not include the -d command.

Comment: So you know that `-d` will run the Docker container in the background.  What's your question?

Comment: Earlier I gave docker ps and it did not list any process, when I add '-a' it showed me all the process running

Comment: I still don't see a question.

Comment: ok, im new so getting confused..Here is the question..I assume - docker run ubuntu:16.04 grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list - command will start a ubuntu container but I dont see it running when I try the 'docker ps' command..Why its not being listed when I enter the 'docker ps' command and when its printing the output, how do I logon to that container.

Comment: Container lifetime is linked to process lifetime. Here you start a grep command, after the end of that command, you're container will be stopped.

Comment: By the time you run `docker ps`, the container has already exited and is no longer running.  Why would you want to "logon" to a container in the middle of a `grep` command?

Comment: I pulled the command from https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/ ...Now, I got it..My goal was to enter into the shell command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that your container has already exited when you check for running containers (`docker ps`)

As `docker ps -a` show all containers: those running and those not running.

Your command `grep` does it job, then exits, so the container exits as well.

`-d` does not make any difference here because the container lives for a really short period of time. But you can still see it's output using `docker logs <container-id>`

---

If you wanna inspect an image, just for fun you can:

```
docker run -it imagename bash
```

(Use `sh` if bash is not available)

Bear in mind that `docker run` create a new container, so changes there will be only in that container. Images are immutable.